# Find total unique moths with years in Pyspark dataframe from Date column

Tags: datetime, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a date column in my data frame which looks like

`+----------+
|DateColumn|
+----------+
|2016-04-30|
|2016-04-01|
|2017-09-03|
|2017-06-30|
|2016-09-01|
|2016-09-30|`

i want total distinct year months in the given column of datafame
eg above have **4** distinct months i.e

> 2016-04, 2017-09, 2017-06, 2016-09

i am using pyspark Dataframes 
i tried

```
newDF.select(month(newDF['dateColumn']),year(newDF['dateColumn'])).show()
```

But here the problem is output is in 2 different columns.unable to figure out  how to apply group-by on it.

P.S : I am bit new to spark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use date_format() to get specific format,

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = df.withColumn('date_col',F.date_format('date_col','yyy-MM'))
df.show()
+--------+
|date_col|
+--------+
| 2016-04|
| 2016-04|
| 2017-09|
| 2017-06|
| 2016-09|
+--------+
```